# "Invalid control category: android.media.intent.category.LIVE_VIDEO"

Tags: android-4.4-kitkat, cyanogenmod, screencast, miracast

Has anyone seen this in logcat before ?

My code:

```
MediaRouteChooserDialogFragment pickerDlg = MediaRouteDialogFactory.getDefault().onCreateChooserDialogFragment();
// Create a route selector for the type of routes your app supports.
MediaRouteSelector selector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
        // These are the framework-supported intents
        .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_VIDEO)
        .build();
pickerDlg.setRouteSelector(selector);
pickerDlg.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "android.support.v7.mediarouter:MediaRouteChooserDialogFragment");
```